# How to get jquery variable value to php variable on select change event without ajax?

Tags: php, jquery

How it's possible to get jquery variable value to PHP variable

My Jquery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){                  

        jQuery("#mec_make").change(function(){
        jQuery("#frame").html('');

        makeval = jQuery(this).val();
        jQuery("#sec").val(makeval);
    });

});
</scipt>
```

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" name="te" value="" id="sec">
```

I'll try to get jquery value in my php code but i cant get it.

PHP

```
  echo $year = '<script>jquery("#sec").val()</script>';
echo $year = '<script>document.write(document.getElementById("sec").value)</script>';
```

i don't need ajax i want it without ajax , i need it when change event fire value will store to php variable.

Full Code

```
<div class="mak" id="mmm"><input type="hidden" name="te" value="" id="sec"></div>

<?php

echo "buddy".$year = '<script>jQuery("#sec").val();</script>';

$get_recent = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_make_details
                             WHERE post_id =".$post_id."
                             AND year =$year
                             AND make_name ='Yamaha'
                            ");

foreach ($get_recent as $key => $rec_value) {
            $rec_value_year_data[] = $rec_value->year;
            $model_name['model_name'] = $rec_value->model_name;
            $datarrr[] =$model_name;
}

?>

<select name="mec_year" id="car_year_select">
             <?php
             $post_id = get_the_ID();
             $inserted_year = get_post_meta($post_id,'year',true);
              echo "<option value=".$inserted_year.">".$inserted_year."</option>"; ?>
                  <script>
                    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                        jQuery("#mec_make").change(function(){
                            jQuery("#frame").html('');
                            makeval = jQuery(this).val();
                            jQuery("#sec").val(makeval);
                        });
                });
            </script>
</select>
```

Comment: `echo $year;` ...

Comment: `echo`it after assignment, not during assignment.

Comment: @Natrium echoit after assignment ?

Comment: `jQuery("#sec").val(makeval);` this is not working??

Comment: @devpro then how can i get that value ?

Comment: currently, you're echoing the result of the assignment, not the variable itself.

Comment: @Natrium ok so give me current way how i get that value ?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to put `mec_make` value into hidden field `id="sec"` than why are you using PHP here, you can get the desired output as:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){                  

        jQuery("#mec_make").change(function(){
        jQuery("#frame").html('');

        makeval = jQuery(this).val();
        jQuery("#sec").val(makeval);
        console.log(jQuery("#sec").val())  ;
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="te" value="" id="sec">
<select name="mec_make" id="mec_make">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option value="1">My Value</option>
</select>
```

Also note that, this `</scipt>` should be `</script>`, fix the typo.

*Now, how can you get the values in php, simple answer use `<form>` and submit button, you will get the values in php.*

Comment: because of i need that value in my sql query so i want to store that value in php variable.

Comment: @maddy: yes, now u can use <form> here, u will get all values in php and u can use them in you query

Comment: without submit on change event?? @maddy

Comment: @maddy: u can use `jQuery( "#yourFormID" ).submit();` after changing the value `jQuery("#sec").val(makeval);` use this line for submition.

Comment: @Natrium how can i put submit script, i need in PHP variable i written like this way echo $year = '<script>jquery("#sec").val()</script>'; so how can i write jQuery( "#yourFormID" ).submit();

Comment: its better to show full code here... i am 100% sure there is no need to use it in php @maddy

Comment: @maddy: checking this

Comment: @devpro what  should i check ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127360/discussion-between-devpro-and-maddy).